# How to show time in front of web service data in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

![enter image description here][1]
Hi
I am getting server data from web socket but i am facing one problem that i need to show current time in the from to front of web service data as show ..I am able to show data but time is not in front of that..:(

How to show time in front of data.

I am using like this

```
function nativePluginResultHandler (result)
{
      $('#realTimeContents' ).append('<p>'+result+'</p>');

}
```

[image]
     !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From this answer: [How to get current time in jquery mobile or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886560/how-to-get-current-time-in-jquery-mobile-or-jquery/17886811?noredirect=1#comment26121764_17886811)

Why wouldn't taking your server's appended results and then prepending with the javascript time stamp work?

```
  $('#time').prepend("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function date() {
    var now = new Date(),
        now = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds();
    $('#time').html(now);
}
```

Fiddle: [`http://jsfiddle.net/u32pU/2/`](http://jsfiddle.net/u32pU/2/)