# How to get current time in jquery mobile or jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to get current time? I want to display current time with text in front of it.

**Example:**

I have to take one div tag in which i have one label (having current time) front of that i want to show some text. How to do that?

Actually my problem is different. I am solving the problem in breaking parts.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery getTime function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670290/jquery-gettime-function)

Comment: text in front it? for what?

Comment: Please solve that question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881261/how-to-show-time-in-front-of-web-service-data-in-jquery-mobile/17881466?noredirect=1#17881466

Answer (score 10):

You'd probably do best just using regular JavaScript for the time: 
The date object has a getTime method:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

```
  var currentTime = new Date()
  var hours = currentTime.getHours()
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()


  if (minutes < 10)
  minutes = "0" + minutes
```

Then, using jQuery you could display it in your div:

```
  $('#divID').html("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b>");
```

You can then prepend any text you want in front of that:

```
  $('#divID').prepend('<p>Text before timestamp<p>');
```

Comment: Now my real question is this ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881261/how-to-show-time-in-front-of-web-service-data-in-jquery-mobile/17881466?noredirect=1#17881466

Comment: Actually i am getting a data from server after a few seconds But it is not sending any time .so i need to show time with data in my screen .So i need to make one div in which i have two div one div have current time and other is data .may i right .can you make any other structure?

Comment: text are not in same line..:( here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DhneL/

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean something like this:

```
function date() {
    var now = new Date(),
        now = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds();
    $('#time').html(now);
}
```

Demo: [`http://jsfiddle.net/u32pU/`](http://jsfiddle.net/u32pU/)

Comment: As  I told you I have big question i am breaking this questions in part why you are not understand..!!

Comment: Now I want to show some text in front of this time .why this is not horizontal ?this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u32pU/1/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/u32pU/2/

Comment: Please solve this question same as 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881261/how-to-show-time-in-front-of-web-service-data-in-jquery-mobile/17881466?noredirect=1#17881466